# How can I get the exact position of the mouse at the time of a screenshot?

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

I am developing a background automation tool in Java that needs to return the exact mouse position when a specific image is detected on the screen.

My logic currently looks something like this:

```
    Point mousePoint;
    BufferedImage screenImage;
    Rectangle screenArea = getScreenArea();

    while(running) {
        mousePoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenArea);
        if(imageContainsKey(screenImage)) return mousePoint;
    }
```

The problem with this logic is that when the mouse is moving, the screen image will be generated when the mouse is at a later position in time. The discrepancy is worse the faster the mouse is moving.

This is what I have tried to solve this problem:

- Reduce screen capture area to reduce time to capture image *(still too much mouse position discrepancy)*
- Try instead to detect mouse position from the screen capture image *(cannot find a java implementation that returns the mouse image as part of the screen capture)*
- Retrieve mouse position and screen image in separate threads running at the same time *(had no noticable impact)*

One possible solution I have yet to try is to have a separate thread which continuously draws a small point at the current mouse position that can be detected in the screen capture image. However I am hoping that there is a better (non-hacky) solution to doing this.

Comment: Can you maybe [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that I can try to replicate the behavior on my machine?